# Visual Studio Code VSC is not able to find the declaration / definition of variables declared in .properties file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

First time writing here.

So I am using VSC as a code editor for Java development. I have an object.properties file that holds values, for example:

```
First.Value=SomeValue
```

Then, I use System properties from Java to get the values, and I store the key of the value in a string, for example:

```
String someKey = "First.Value"
```

Then, I am able to pull the value as follows:

```
Properties prop...
prop.load(new FileInputStream("object.properties"));
prop.getProperty(someKey);
```

However, when I hover above First.Value on the statement below it cannot find where this is declared. The difference is that IntelliJ is able to go to the declaration, whereas VSC not. I attempt to find the declaration of the First.Value below:

```
String someKey = "First.Value"
```

Is there a way VSC can find this declaration (goto definition), otherwise, I need to manually search the key First.Value at object.properties. Again, IntelliJ is able to do this.

Please let me know if I can clarify better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your declaration vscode regards it as a simple String description statement. After all, getting the file content is done at compile time. I have submitted this feature you want to GitHub

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind sharing the link to the request with me?

Comment: The previously submitted issue has been deleted by them. Now resubmit it. Here is the link:https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2347

Comment: He gave some replies. Please check them in time